Abelian vs non-abelian discrete symmetries in neutrino physics
I was reading about the parametrization of the PMNS matrix and stumbled upon an article of Serguey Petcov$^1$ about discrete flavour symmetries. It endeavors to see if there is a pattern induced by a non-abelian discrete groups that controls the mixing angles and CP violation phases. I loved this idea but could not see why we need a non-abelian AND a discrete group for this.
I found an article entitled Non-Abelian Discrete Symmetries in Particle Physics, in which they assert that:

Abelian discrete symmetries, $Z_N$ , are also often imposed in order to control allowed couplings for particle physics, in particular model-building beyond the standard model. In addition to Abelian discrete symmetries, non-Abelian discrete symmetries have also been applied for model-building in particle physics, in particular to understand the three-generation flavor structure.

Yet I still dont understand how these discrete symmetries can contribute to model building in different ways here. I know from my particle physics course that the non abelian character of gauge groups manifest itself in the self-niteraction of the fields, is it also the case here? I also know that we have used an approximate SU(3) flavor group to represent the quark model, so why not use it here too? and why must it be non abelian?

https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6158-5

https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3552



I am going to give you a partial response that hopefully will help you clear some concepts about symmetries in particle physics. I will not focus on the papers that you are reading.
Part 1: Discrete global symmetries

Yet I still don't understand how these discrete symmetries can contribute to model building in different ways here.

If we impose that a theory must respect invariance under a symmetry group $G$, it means that we are only allowed to write terms in our Lagrangian that respect/are invariant under such a symmetry. We can do this with both continuous (global or gauge) and discrete symmetries. Let me give you an example of discrete symmetry:
Let a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ scalar theory with a field $\phi$, whose symmetry acts on $\phi$ as
$$
\mathbb{Z}_2: \quad \phi \to -\phi.
$$
What terms does this forbid on our Lagrangian? Well, any term $\phi^n$ with $n$ odd will go to $-\phi^n$ under the transformation. Thus such terms are prohibited in the theory!
This can be generalised quite straightforwardly to $\mathbb{Z}_N$, with
$$
\mathbb{Z}_N: \quad \phi \to e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}}\phi.
$$
to forbid terms that are of the form $\phi^n$, where $n \not\equiv 0 \pmod{N}$. As a physical example, the case of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is sometimes used for C, P or T transformations (if we consider they are a good symmetry of the theory). I am sure you can generalise this to non-abelian discrete groups, and that this has some nice properties, but that goes beyond my expertise. Sorry :(
Part 2: Continuous global symmetries

I know from my particle physics course that the non abelian character of gauge groups manifest itself in the self-interaction of the fields, is it also the case here? I also know that we have used an approximate SU(3) flavor group to represent the quark model, so why not use it here too?

Now we go to something more interesting, continuous symmetries. These come in two main categories: global and gauge. The difference between these two categories is usually misunderstood when first meeting them (as happened to me!).
The global symmetries are the generalisation of the above discrete case. A physical example that you are familiar with is the approximate global symmetry of the QCD chiral Lagrangian, $SU(3)$, which is used to give rise to mesons and baryons. This is also useful to put constrains on the allowed terms of the Lagrangian. These continuous symmetries can also help us recover the "low energy" behaviour of the theory, through spontaneous symmetry breaking (as in the chiral $SU(3)$ case). These symmetries do not give rise to self interaction.
Part 3: Gauge symmetries
The gauge symmetries are a redundancy of the theory and are extremely interesting, as they are the best tool we have to make physical theories. We can introduce gauge fields, which transform under the gauge group but without changing the physics (even if they do). Again, our Lagrangian must be invariant under these gauge transformations. These gauge fields are dynamical and are described through Yang-Mills theory. In the non-abelian case, these theories have self-interaction and many other complex phenomena.
Possibly familiar cases of gauge groups are the $U(1)$ symmetry of Maxwell's theory or the $SU(3)$ of QCD, which describes gluons and has nothing to do with the flavour/chiral $SU(3)$.
Edit: Actually discrete symmetries can also be gauged, to protect them from gravity and other global symmetry-breaking effects.

Last words
I hope this answer will help you see the differences between the different kinds of symmetries. If you do, you should have a much better understanding of why each symmetry is used in the papers you are citing. Good luck ;)
